# render FlatList only when data is present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I run a graphql query and depending on the data, render a flatList.

```
  const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
    //onCompleted: _onCompleted,
    onError: _onGetMyProfileQueryError,
  });
....
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeView}>
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.listHolder}>
          <FlatList
            data={data ? data.me.friends : null}
            horizontal={false}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Friend
                friend={item}
                onDeleteFriend={onDeleteFriend}
                originatorId={data ? data.me.id : null}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(data: any) => '3'}
            ListEmptyComponent={renderEmptyContainer()}
          />
        </View>
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

However, currently, I have to use ternary operators for checks like `data? data.me.friends: null` in the `FlatList` to avoid Typescript errors. If the query fails, and the data is null, It disturbs the whole performance and I will have to use multiple if-else within the whitelist item component too.

So I am looking for the best way such that data is passed into the Flatlist only when the mutation is successful. I could use `onCompleted` for that but I am not sure how to organize it such that no flat list is displayed from the main return when there's an error.

Also, currently, I am using the same key for all elements of the list but it shouldn't be like that obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render your list when you have data, In this way, you will also have better performance when lesser things are rendered so `it will be a conditional rendering of your Flatlist`.

```
{data && data.me && data.me.friends.lenght > 0 &&
    <FlatList
        data={data.me.friends}
        horizontal={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Friend
            friend={item}
            onDeleteFriend={onDeleteFriend}
            originatorId={data ? data.me.id : null}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(data: any) => '3'}
        ListEmptyComponent={renderEmptyContainer()}
      />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `data={data?.me?.friends}`

You can also use this syntax `data={data ? data?.me?.friends : []}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to used as

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeView}>
  <Container style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.listHolder}>
      <FlatList
        data={data?.me?.friends || []}
        horizontal={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Friend
            friend={item}
            onDeleteFriend={onDeleteFriend}
            originatorId={data ? data.me.id : null}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(data: any) => '3'}
        ListEmptyComponent={renderEmptyContainer()}
      />
    </View>
  </Container>
</SafeAreaView>
```

**data={data?.me?.friends || []}** you have to use this that I have already mentioned in the code
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining This link will also useful

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.